# Proof that $f(z) = cosec(\pi z)$ has simple poles

Tags: complex-analysis

In my book they say that $$f(z) = \csc(\pi z)=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$$ has simple poles, however doesn't explain why.

I tried do to the following: I know it should have simple poles where $g(z) = \sin(\pi z)$ has zeroes, i.e. $z = k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then I can check if they are indeed simple poles with the following:$$\lim_{z\to k}(z-k)\csc(\pi z) = \lim_{z\to k}\frac{z-k}{\sin(\pi z)} = \lim_{z\to k}\frac{1}{\pi\cos(\pi z)}=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\pi} & k \,\,\text{even} \\
      -\frac{1}{\pi} & k \,\, \text{odd} 
   \end{cases} \neq 0$$
hence a simple poles at $z = k\in\mathbb{Z}$? I am not sure this is correct or if this is the shorter/best way to show this.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 3):

$f(z)=cosec (\pi z)=\frac {1}{\sin(\pi z)}=\frac {1}{\pi z-\frac{\pi^3z^3}{3!}+\frac{\pi^5z^5}{5!}-\cdots}=\frac {1}{\pi -\frac{\pi^3z^2}{3!}+\frac{\pi^5z^4}{5!}-\cdots}\times \frac 1 z$

So $z=0$ is a simple pole and residue at $z=0$ is $\displaystyle\lim_{z=0}zf(z)=\frac 1 \pi$